# excel, get number from 1 table, and sum based on criteria in 2nd

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables:

```
 name   date    param   if
DO03    1999-05-01  1,18    no
AM01    1999-05-02  2,15    no
AM01    1999-05-03  1,98    no
AM01    1999-05-04  2,05    yes
MA03    1999-05-05  1,50    no
MA02    1999-05-05  1,45    yes
AM01    1999-05-07  2,22    no
AM02    1999-05-08  1,56    no
SA02    1999-05-09  1,60    yes
MA03    1999-05-11  1,05    yes
MA02    1999-05-12  1,52    no
SA01    1999-05-13  2,17    yes
CY01    1999-05-14  2,00    yes
SA03    1999-05-15  0,97    yes
MA03    1999-05-16  1,11    no
DO01    1999-05-18  1,89    yes
MA01    1999-05-19  1,95    no
AM03    1999-05-20  0,95    yes
AM03    1999-05-21  1,20    yes
SA01    1999-05-23  1,90    no
AM01    1999-05-24  1,97    no
DO01    1999-05-25  2,10    yes
SA03    1999-05-26  1,15    no
AM01    1999-05-27  2,12    yes
DO02    1999-05-28  1,47    yes
CY03    1999-05-29  0,94    no
CY02    1999-05-30  1,48    no
```

and

```
 name   type param price
CY03    M   1,0 12,50
    DO03    M   1,0 13,00 
    AM03    M   1,0 14,00 
    MA03    M   1,0 15,00 
    SA03    M   1,0 16,00 
    CY02    S   1.5 18,75 
    DO02    S   1.5 19,50 
    AM02    S   1.5 21,00 
    MA02    S   1.5 22,50 
    SA02    S   1.5 24,00 
    CY01    D   2,0 25,00 
    DO01    D   2,0 26,00 
    AM01    D   2,0 28,00 
    MA01    D   2,0 30,00 
    SA01    D   2,0 32,00
```

What i'm trying to do.
I want to sum prices of all products where 'yes' value is.

f.e. When in 1st table there is 'yes' (so first is AM01), I want get this product price from 2nd table, and another with yes, and another, etc..
and sum it into one value.
I tried with sumif, sumifs but this is a little bit harder than usual sumif exercises.
For any suggestions I will be grateful.

EDIT: Forgotten - i managed to do it with temp column when I get this price via vlookup function for each row, and then sum this new column. But is there any way to do this in one command?

Comment: Looks like you'll want to throw in a VLookup first then do your calculations or combine IF, VLOOKUP then sum the column with that calculation.

Comment: Using your provided sample data, is your expected total `222` (sum the "yes" values only once per unique "yes" value) or `290` (sum each "yes" value individually regardless of duplicates)?

Comment: 290, regardless of duplicates.

Comment: You could create a user defined function if that is feasible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SUMIF() in a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D28="yes")*(SUMIF(G2:G16,A2:A28,J2:J16)))
```

But you probably use `;` instead of `,` as the deliniator between criteria, so use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D28="yes")*(SUMIF(G2:G16;A2:A28;J2:J16)))
```

[image]